# How to get selected items in the checklistbox

Tags: vb.net

I made a program to populate checklistbox2 when checklistbox items is checked. Here I got the result but the process is taken in a different way.

The problem is that checklistbox2 is populating when 3 times clicks on a listbox in checkedlistbox1

```
Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Data Source=xxx;Provider=xxxx; User Id=xxxx; Password=xxx")
        Dim dt2 As New DataTable
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Step i + 1
            If CheckedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i) = CheckState.Checked Then
                Dim xx As String = (CType(CheckedListBox1.Items(i), DataRowView))("name")
                Dim sqlstr2 As String = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                Dim command2 As New OleDbCommand(sqlstr2, connection)
                Dim adpt2 As New OleDbDataAdapter(command2)
                adpt2.SelectCommand = command2
                adpt2.Fill(dt2)
                CheckedListBox2.DataSource = dt2
                CheckedListBox2.DisplayMember = "name"
                CheckedListBox2.ValueMember = "name"
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: May I know why you are using `Step i + 1`

Comment: Its because of the checklistbox1 contain more than one items..checking each items are checked or not

Comment: But why it can't be Step 1. Making step i + 1 makes Step = 1 in first iteration then in subsequent iteration it becomes 2 + 1 = 3...It's not going sequentially.

Comment: then how to give..please give suggestions

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Can you remove Step and check once

Comment: You provided the code where the `CheckedListBox2` get loaded but you should also provide the code that's triggering it.

Comment: I just tested and `Step i + 1` will go sequentially... You can remove the hole step parameter and your for will do exactly the same.  You don't need to specify a step value if you want an increment of 1 because it's the default value.  If you want a different value, just specify the step value (`Step 2`) and forget about the variable name (in VB... C# is an other thing)

Comment: my output was correct..but problem is not populating checkedlistbox2 when the items checked..its populating when its uncheck..for that what i do guyz

Comment: Just FYI, this code is pretty bad. You're creating a new sql connection for each checked item in the list and updating the checked list box for each checked item on the list. Extract the checked items to a new list then run all your inserts/updates/whatever in that one connection, then update the checked list box once after the fact. I wouldn't be surprised if that's part of your problem.

Comment: thanks for all..i got the result..i just put this code in to   Private Sub CheckedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
-----end sub ;)...now its working perfectly